# Typo3 version 8.x Exception "Connection pool was not found"

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.7.x

I'm using Query builder functionality in typo3 8, Now I'm receiving this exception.

**Below is my error**

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool' not found
```

**Below is my source code**

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

*
*
*

public function getItems($Variable1,$Variable2)
{
   $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_xxxxxx');
   $statement = $queryBuilder
      ->select('*')
      ->from('tx_xxxxxx AS txx')
      ->where(
          $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('txx.field_name_1',$Variable1),
          $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('txx.field_name_2',$Variable2)
      )
      ->execute();
   return $statement->fetch();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the source code?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a reason of missing `\` (backslash) from the starting point of your class namespace.

try this `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class);`

Comment: That's it, Great Thanks